# Fine-tune laptop screen brightness which is too low or too high?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display

I have a Lenovo E570, Windows 10 and I want to know, how to change or fine-tune the screen brightness. I don't want higher brightness than it already is at max, nor do I want it dimmer than it's lowest settings.

I change the brightness by pressing the F keys on the keyboard and I can change the brightness in 10 units. But the units are not equal where 1 is super low and 2 is bright and then 2-8 have almost no differences and then 9-10 and max. Can I have more units like 1.3 or like that?

If not, is there an application that can help me similar to the night mode that makes it all red but instead of red, the whole colours just dim?

Comment: Has your laptop screen ever been replaced? I’ve seen this behavior with compatibility issues using aftermarket screens. In addition, you should try to update the BIOS, all drivers and all utility applications for this model of laptop from Lenovo’s website.

Answer (score 1):

You might see if you can change the brightness directly in Windows instead of using the F keys.
Try power options.
Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings

For applications, I like f.lux, https://justgetflux.com/

Once F.lux is running, Brightness can be manually adjusted using Alt + PgUp & Alt + PgDn and whitebalance changes can be disabled by manually setting a color balance.